# Is there any drawback to using the same TensorFlow Session multiple times when only inputs change?

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, inference

I always see examples that create a new TensorFlow Session each time they do inference but it seems somewhat slower than reusing the same Session (with new input through feed_dict). Am I missing something?

P.S.: the setting I am working in is a kind of online inference service where you send me an image and I give you back something. I do not want to recreate the Session for each request.

Comment: Yes, it is better to reuse the session if you are going to do inference multiple times. Be aware that sessions take resources (memory, GPU, ...), so you only want to keep them alive if you are really using them frequently, and always remembering to close them cleanly on exit or failure.